# Do not stop on memcache fatal error in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using `memcache` in my `php` code:

```php
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
$memcache->set($key, serialize($Rows), MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 36000);
```

However, under certain circumstances, the `set` instruction produces the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 28037120 bytes)
```

I don't want to raise, `php`'s `memory_limit`, I'd simply go on ignoring the `$memcache->set` line, I'd make something like:

```php
try {
    $memcache->set($key, serialize($Rows), MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 36000);
} catch(...) {
    // do nothing
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: you can't. Fix your memory leak.

Comment: you have to release memory for `$row ` array.

Comment: A check on available storage space?

```
$serial = serialize($Rows);
if ($memcache->getStats()['bytes'] + strlen($serial) < $memcache->getStats()['limit_maxbytes'])
 $memcache->set($key, $serial, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 36000);
```

But it doesn't seem to work... Why?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the error you get is not the `set` interface of the memcache but the `serialize()` call you made.

Even the question is not give to readers any kind of tip about the value of `$rows`, you are probably trying to serialize:

1. a huge stack of objects/values (a lot of items in `$rows`) which is not possible to fit into the memory in one shot when they are serialized.
2. Some of the objects/values in `$rows` are not serializable? Resources?
3. Some of the objects/values in `$rows` have circular references (Common scenario with doctrine entities)

Potential solutions could be:

1. Reduce the amount of items in your stack. Try applying a batch processing (serialize items in `$rows` in chunks) or simply increase the [memory_limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits)
2. Don't try to serialize non serializable things such as resources.
3. Carefully implement `__wakeup` and `__sleep` in your objects used in `$rows` and only return/use the properties which is meaningful there.

Personally I always prefer simpler JSON structures in Memcache rather than relying on the output of the `serialize()` and `unserialize()` because at some point in your development cycle, you may easily and silently loose some properties of your objects when you serialize them and you can get a different or meaningless object when you unserialize it back. This can be lead to bugs which are pretty hard to understand and debug. Also json/array transformations in PHP is pretty easy and straightforward. They don't need to involve `__magic`.

Hope it helps.